# Potential divider

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I am just wondering if a potential divider circuit is used to vary the pd across the other resistor from zero to maximum, why can't the variation be done straight from the source?

Comment: What do you mean 'straight from the source?'

Comment: say if we are using a power pack to supply the voltage, can't we just change the setting to different volts every time to get a varied reading of current ?

Comment: Are you talking abou [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)? As you can see, a voltage divider, fixes a fraction of the incoming potential, and so the incoming potential *can* actually vary, and is expected to vary.

Comment: According to your comment on FGSUZ's answer, you are trying to replicate an experiment described in a text book.  If you have an adjustable _[bench power supply](https://www.amazon.com/Eventek-KPS305D-Adjustable-Switching-Regulated/dp/B071RNT1CD/)_, that would be ideal:  A student-quality bench power supply typically has dual voltage and current readouts, and knobs that you can use to limit either one while watching how the other changes.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving aside that potential dividers are used for many more things, suppose a practical situation:

a complex circuit might have very different elements. Suppose you need many different inputs. For example, you need $20V$ in one terminal, and $5V$ in another terminal. Well, instead of buying two power sources, which are expensive, you can take two wires of 20V. One of them goes straight to one terminal, and the other one is reduced to 5V using a potential divider.

Now, you can expand this to so many terminals.

A good example is electronic circuits with transistors. See the image:
[image: Circuit with MOS transistors]

### As you can see in red, there are so many different voltages across the circuit, and that's due to resistances. Without them, you'd need so many power sources.

EDIT:

> Why can't the components be placed in a simple circuit where the pd is changed from the power pack itself

Okay, you should have said it clearer from the beginning haha. There's nothing wrong with changing the power of the source itself. It is sometimes done like that.

The only reason I think you use a resistance is for safety. I'll explain: suppose you want to evaluate an unknown element, or you are careless enough to plug it in a dangerous way. The worst thing you could do is connecting a short-circuit.

This is more usual than you might think. For exampole, a diode can already behave like a short-ciurcit for not very high voltages.

If you plugged that diode to the power source directly, you'd be creating a short-circuit on the source, and that's dangerous. You can even burn the source, because the intensity would be very high.

In contrast, if there is a resistance in the middle (which can be the first resistance of the potential divider), the risk is gone. Why? Because now the worst thing that can happen is that you connect a short-circuit. That's the same as conencting a wire. But the wire would be after a resistance, so the worst thing you can do is now a circuit with one resistance. The resistance limits the current capable to flow, so it reduces risks so much.

Comment: that is a very good example, so thanks, but at the moment I am reading about investigating the characteristics of different components like bulb, wire and thermistor and when these components are placed in potential divider circuit and different values of I and V are obtained, the book says to plot a graph of I against V to see the behaviour of their resistance, and I was thinking why can't the components be placed in a simple circuit where the pd is changed from the power pack itself

Comment: Okay, see the edit.